# while closing a workbook in excel, save/don't save prompt is not coming

Tags: excel

Whenever I close my workbook that is not saved in my system, There is no pop-up cor dialogue box of save/don't save coming. I want that dialogue box every time I close my workbook without saving.Let me know about the options or setting I need change for doing the same.

Comment: I'm voting to close this questions since it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: 1. Does this happen with XLSX or just XLSM/XLSB workbooks? 2. Are you on an active directory network with governed user permissions? 3. Do you have a personal macros workbook? 4. Are macros enabled? 5. Do you have any Add-ins installed? The list goes on and on.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you disabled alerts? Open VBA editor (Alt+F11), then immediate window (Ctrl+G) and run this command `Application.DisplayAlerts = True`.